# Access denied while creating subsite from workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, rest

I am following [this](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/articletype/articleview/articleid/8661/create-site-from-template-using-sharepoint-2013-workflow) article to create a subsite from workflow.

I am getting following error

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you granted the workflow full crontrol on collecteion level? If not that's more likely the reason.

Find the workflow app id (Between | and @) here: `/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx?Scope=Web`

Enter the app id here: `/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`

Enter this xml in the xml field (No placeholders):

```
 <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
 <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
```

Hit the create button.

Now in the workflow put the http request in an App step

Full guide here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo