# Dynamically get field from workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am creating a site wide workflow. I want to generate a workflow that gets a particular field from a list and displays it as part of the process.

For example - CurrentList.Owners

However, I cannot see the field "Owners" in the CurrentList options on SharePoint Designer. I can hard code it as below;

MyList.Owners

Not every site is going to have this Library but I do know that every site will have a library containing the Owners field in order to run the workflow.

Is there a way I can dynamically get the fields available to the current library?

Comment: Use REST calls: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153058/sharepoint-online-office-365-using-rest-services-in-a-sharepoint-designer-work

Comment: @DannyEngelman I am using an on premise system, not sure if that makes a difference. I did try a "get http..." via SharePoint designer and appended what looks like a rest call there but that wasn't' working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think this is possible. The only way I've seen to use a column in a site workflow is for that column to be a site column. Even if you created a site column of type Lookup, it would still need the list/library defined at the time you create it.

Comment: This, unfortunately, appears to be the case.